# Referencing a file not in the project solution c#

Tags: c#, file

Struggling with a small part to a recent assignment, we've been asked to provide only the .cs file during the hand in process of our assignment, however it also asks us to reference a .txt file. Without setting the exact path to my file (ie: c:\users\username\documents etc).

The program is console based as this is just an algorithm and structure class, but I'm still a little miffed on how to reference without having the reference be static, or the txt document being added to a solution.

I've considered asking for the directory path input at the start of the program, but I just wondered if there was a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the file from the application's directory, for example using this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("myfile.txt"))
```

Comment: We're using C# and as I said, we can only hand in the .cs file, not a solution folder. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: But the assignment is to "reference" a txt file. If you only can hand in a .cs file, your code can safely assume the .txt file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 2):

You've pretty much covered the options.  If you can *only* provide that cs file then you can only:

- Hard-code the location in the file as an absolute path - e.g. `c:\testfile.txt`
- Hard-code the location as a relative path - e.g. `..\testfile.txt`
- Get the location as a command line argument
- Make the console program interactive and prompt for the location after it starts
- Get the location from an environment variable

Comment: Okay well then I'll probably take the user input in that case, thanks for the swift help :)